# why wildfly can't start running jboss server

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, ojdbc

I'm trying to patch Jboss 7.4.12 from 7.4.0 and it has been successfully patched and this problem has been faced when I tried to add ojdbc to it 21.11.0.0:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
    ("server-ssl-context" => "applicationSSC")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.security.ssl-context.applicationSSC" => "java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed"}}
02:53:04,622 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report

ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.4.12.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.29.Final-redhat-00001) started (with errors) in 2120ms - Started 317 of 557 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 343 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)


 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "elytron"),
    ("server-ssl-context" => "applicationSSC")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.security.ssl-context.applicationSSC" => "java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed"}}
02:53:04,622 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
```